# Issues with count(distinct) and partition by

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres.

My SQL is incredibly rusty and I'd greatly appreciate some advice to help me overcome my problem.

I want to find situations where 2+ cars were sold at exactly the same time, were the same make, but were different models

If I `COUNT(model) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp, make)` I also get situations where cars of the same model are included in the view with no way to filter them out.

I have tried using distinct count: `COUNT(DISTINCT model) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp, make)`, which would work perfectly however counting distinct whilst partitioning is not allowed.

I would ideally like a solution where I don't have to join to the same table using an inequality join as I'm going to be querying a large dataset and performance is important.

Apologies if the solution to this is incredibly simple but, for the life of me, I cannot work it out.

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Note: I don't care about the count column, it was just to help describe the problem

Thanks very much

Comment: If you don't care about the count column then your current output already matches your desired output.

Comment: This is a good point and I haven't explained myself very well - apologies.

I only want sales on the same timestamp, same make but different models in the view. I don't want to see any instances where there was only one sale per timestamp or any instances where the model was the same when partitioned by timestamp and make.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dense_rank` and then get the maximum of those:

```
SELECT timestamp, make, model,
       max(rank) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp, make) AS count
FROM (SELECT timestamp, make, model,
             dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp, make ORDER BY model) AS rank,
             count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp, make) AS num
      FROM cars) AS q
WHERE num > 1;

 timestamp  │    make    │ model  │ count 
════════════╪════════════╪════════╪═══════
 2022-01-01 │ Ford       │ Fiesta │     2
 2022-01-01 │ Ford       │ Focus  │     2
 2022-01-01 │ Volkswagen │ Golf   │     2
 2022-01-01 │ Volkswagen │ Polo   │     2
 2022-01-03 │ Ford       │ Focus  │     1
 2022-01-03 │ Ford       │ Focus  │     1
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - the only issue with this is that then car sales occurring once per timestamp appear in the view as well. I can get a view of all instances where > 1 sales are on a single timestamp and then implement this but it becomes very convoluted, was hoping there was a simpler solution!

Comment: I didn't get from your question that you don't want these in the result, but it is ieasy to exclude groups with a size of one.

Comment: Yeah you're right, having a complete brain lapse. This works great, thank you!